# Unity3D GUI Keyboard Navigation

Tags: user-interface, input, keyboard, unity-game-engine

I have coded functionality for my menu script that allows the buttons composing the menu to be navigated through (Via changing the focus from button to button with GUI.FocusControl()). However, I am baffled as to how to "activate"/"select" the button that is currently focused on. Ideally, the user can navigate up and down through the menu and press "enter" when the user is at the option he or she wishes to select. Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to do this but eventually I found the solution. If you're still looking for an answer here is how I do it. Basically you want to make use of the SelctionGrid function of the GUI class. You can take a peak [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.SelectionGrid.html) to see how it works but here's some code with a working example of what you are asking for:

```
#pragma strict
@script ExecuteInEditMode;

var selGridInt : int = 0;    //This integer is the index of the button we are hovering above or have selected

var selStrings : String[] = ["Grid 1", "Grid 2", "Grid 3", "Grid 4"];

private var maxButton : int;    // The total number of buttons in our grid

function Start()
{
    maxButton = selStrings.Length;    // Set the total no. of buttons to our String array size
}

function Update()
{
    // Get keyboard input and increase or decrease our grid integer
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        // Here we want to create a wrap around effect by resetting the selGridInt if it exceeds the no. of buttons
        if(selGridInt > 0)
        {
            selGridInt--;
        }
        else
        {
            selGridInt = maxButton - 1;
        }
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        // Create the same wrap around effect as above but alter for down arrow
        if(selGridInt < (maxButton-1))
        {
            selGridInt++;
        }
        else
        {
            selGridInt = 0;
        }
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Return))
    {
        switch(selGridInt)
        {
            case 0: Debug.Log("Button "+(selGridInt + 1 )+ " pressed.");
                break;
            case 1: Debug.Log("Button "+(selGridInt + 1 )+" pressed.");
                break;
            case 2: Debug.Log("Button "+(selGridInt + 1 )+ " pressed.");
                break;
            case 3: Debug.Log("Button "+(selGridInt + 1 )+ " pressed.");
                break;
        }
    }
}

function OnGUI () 
{
    selGridInt = GUI.SelectionGrid (Rect (Screen.width/2-75, Screen.height/2-25, 150, 200), selGridInt, selStrings, 1);
}
```